# Producing My Position

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> Usually, I'm seen at a mass movement,
>   Or alongside some cutting bloke.
>   A keen eye can be rude about me.
>   My sister was there when God spoke.
>
> Many would say I'm a sequence,
>   Passed between fixed amounts of me.
>   The French say I go in Switzerland.
>   In some fish, I show enormity.

**What am I?**
**Please explain each line in your answer.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you may be a

> **gene**

Usually, I'm seen at a mass movement,

> generally - is usually, with rally being a mass movement.

Or alongside some cutting bloke.

> Gene Hackman - the American who won a best actor Oscar for The French Connection.

A keen eye can be rude about me.

> sageness - being wise and sass is cheek.

My sister was there when God spoke.

> Gene**sis** - "Let there be light"

Many would say I'm a sequence,

> gene - a sequence of nucleotides in DNA or RNA located on a chromosome.

Passed between fixed amounts of me.

> generations - gene rations (fixed amounts) are passed between generations.

The French say I go in Switzerland.

> Gene**va** - with va (go in French) gives the Swiss city.

In some fish, I show enormity.

> hugeness - the huss is a dogfish.

Title: Producing My Position

> Producing is generating, and rating is a position on a scale.

Comment: Well done Tom! You seem to be very good at these.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but are you

> a LOCUS?

Title:

> the locus of a moving object produces its position over time.

*Usually, I'm seen at a mass movement,*

> A physics problem with a point mass moving along some curve which we call its locus.

*Or alongside some cutting bloke.*

> I suspect this is a wordplay line, perhaps changing the word LOCUS somehow to get another similar word.

*A keen eye can be rude about me.*

> A keen eye has FOCUS. Perhaps "rude" reflects that, at least in some fonts/handwriting, an f looks a bit like an l which is CROSSED?

*My sister was there when God spoke.*

> Again I guess this is wordplay: a word similar to locus which is a Biblical character.

*Many would say I'm a sequence,*
*Passed between fixed amounts of me.*

> How would you draw a locus? By marking out points at fixed amounts along it and joining them together.

*The French say I go in Switzerland.*

> Not sure about this, but French for locus is LIEU and for Switzerland is SUISSE. One doesn't quite fit inside the other ...

*In some fish, I show enormity.*

> Apparently a "locus fish" is a [grouper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grouper), and locus also has a [biological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_(genetics)) meaning ...

Comment: I find this mostly unconvincing :-) but if it's right then I suspect the "mass movement" is about insects rather than physics.

Comment: Might have to do something with churches, too?

Comment: This is a nice idea but not the correct answer I'm afraid - it only really fits the title and first line well. There is much more wordplay involved.

Comment: Yeah, I have a bunch of wordplay-ish theories none of which I have been able to make work.